# Asynchronous condition in Angular routing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-router

I am using Angular and I depending of an asynchronous function (`foo(): Promise<boolean>`) I want to show either component `Foo` or `Bar`.

What would be the best approach for this? I don't think route guards are the best fit for my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends where you are executing `foo()` function. Generally yes, you can do it with Route Guards, but you can also do it in TypeScript file of the Component where the `foo()` function is executed.

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

...

constructor(private router: Router) { }

...

navigateToComponent = async () => {
  try{
    result = await foo();
    if(result == 'Foo') this.router.navigate(['/Foo']);
    if(result == 'Bar') this.router.navigate(['/Bar']);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', error);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe, in this case a route guard might be the best option. I will give this a try, thanks!

Comment: If you have to do this on app initialization, you can do it in `app.component.ts`.

Comment: It's rather on runtime and evaluation. I get a url and have to decide what component I can show